# Error when trying to copy file to AWS S3 store

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having trouble copying files to my AWS S3 store.

This AWS command works fine:

```
aws s3 ls myS3store.images
```

It lists all the files and folders in the root folder of my s3 store.

However, whenever I try to copy anything to the s3 store, like this:

```
aws s3 cp c:/filesToUpload/testFile.txt s3://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/myS3store.images
```

I get this error:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation:
>   Access Denied

Here's the policy for my bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy145456543484",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt148515623455446",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myS3store.images",
                "arn:aws:s3:::myS3store.images/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "x.x.x.0/24",
                        "x.x.x.0/24",
                        "x.x.x.x",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there anything else I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
aws s3 cp c:/filesToUpload/testFile.txt s3://myS3store.images
```

The way you have it, it's trying to write to a bucket named `s3.console.aws.amazon.com` which you probably don't own.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I always thought you needed the full path to the bucket.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell not in this case. The `s3://` pseudo-scheme only expects bucket or bucket/key (contextual).  Note that if you really have uppercase characters and/or dots in your bucket name, you don't want to do that -- you will eventually run into compatibility issues if you don't stick to lowercase, numbers, and `-` dashes. Examples... most S3 regions don't allow uppercase, so you can have issues if you try the same thing in different regions, and S3 Transfer Acceleration doesn't support bucket names with dots due to limitations in the way SSL certificates match hostname patterns.